# The data source does not support sorting

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I have a Dynamic Data `LINQ to SQL` ASP.Net Website in `VB.NET`, and am having a little trouble with **Sorting of my GridView and a Search routine** I have implemented. On `Page_Load`, the GridView is sorted by a field (`Departments.department`) in `ASC` order. However, when I perform a search using the code below, I get an error

> The Data Source Does Not Support Sorting.

I'm assuming the problem comes when the `Page_Load` event tries to sort the data after a Search is made, because of the `DataSource/ID`.

```
Dim button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
If button.ID = btnMultiColumnSearchClear.ID Then
    txbMultiColumnSearch.Text = [String].Empty
Else
    Using Data As New wcPhonesDataContext()
        Dim EmployeeNameString As String = txbMultiColumnSearch.Text
        Dim SearchResults = Data.Employees.Where(Function(Employees) Employees.Employee.Contains(EmployeeNameString))

        GridView1.DataSourceID = ""
        GridView1.DataSource = SearchResults
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Using
End If
```

**SOLVED**, but now I have a new problem, here is the code I used to solve this issue...

```
    Dim button = DirectCast(sender, Button)
    If button.ID = btnMultiColumnSearchClear.ID Then
        txbMultiColumnSearch.Text = [String].Empty
    Else
        Using Data As New wcPhonesDataContext()
            Dim EmployeeNameString As String = txbMultiColumnSearch.Text
            Dim SearchResults = Data.Employees.Where(Function(Employees) Employees.Employee.Contains(EmployeeNameString))

            GridView1.Sort("", SortDirection.Ascending)
            GridView1.DataSourceID = ""
            GridView1.DataSource = SearchResults
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Using
    End If
```

I have created a new error though. It occurs if I perform a second search without going BACK to the Employees table.

*'GridView1' fired event Sorting which wasn't handled.*

Comment: Have you tried setting the datasource to `Nothing` before re-assigning the query?

Comment: I was able to fix that issue by clearing the Sort of the DGV, but now I get the above error if I perform a second search without going back to the Employees table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a SqlDataSource and connect the gridview to the data source with a datasourceid, then sorting is done for you magically. You don't have to do anything to support it.

But if set the datasource to some object that you have created in code, sorting does NOT magically happen for you. When the user clicks on a column head, this fires an OnSorting event. You have to write code to handle the event. Typically this mean regenerating the data in the desired order, or regenerating the data and then sorting it.

For example, if you generate the data with a SQL query, I sometimes create a function that runs the SQL query and returns a DataSet. This function takes the sort field as a parameter, which it pastes into the SQL query. Then for the initial display call this function passing in the default sort order, and for the OnSorting call this function passing in the desired sort field.

Comment: Jay, thank you for commenting. I have looked at your SqlDataSource suggestion. My problem is that this is a Dynamic Data site using LINQ to SQL, so I have not actually coded any SQL queries, this is all done behind the scenes and the GridView is populated dynamically at runtime. The only function of this website I have actually written the code for myself is this search function, which according to you, broke the "magic" sorting. It works fine the first time a search is done, the 2nd search, or clicking clear, breaks it. I may need a "workaround" more than I need a "fix"

Comment: Jay, I thought some more about how similar your suggestion was to some Googling I had already done, and fingured heck, i'll give it a shot, and BINGO, it worked. I had thought it would require a lot of coding I didn't particularly want to tackle, but it was as easy as you had said, so thank you!

Comment: Personally, I used to do a lot of SqlDataSource's to get the free sorting. But I'm moving away from that because I've had a number of cases where I've found that I had to turn a SqlDataSource into something created in code, and so I then have to rework everything. So now I often bite the bullet and just do it in code to begin with. You could probably debate this endlessly.